# I run this code and I get the following error. How do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, placeholder

This is a code to predict stock price movements using TensorFlow and the ReLu activation function. I run the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as web

dataset = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source = 'yahoo', start = '1989-01-01', end = '2019-12-25')

import math

close_price = dataset.filter(['Close']).values
data_train_len = math.ceil(len(close_price) * .8)

sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
sc_data = sc.fit_transform(close_price)

data_train = sc_data[0 : data_train_len, : ]
xtrain = []
ytrain = []
for i in range(60, len(data_train)):
    xtrain.append(data_train[i - 60 : i, 0])
    ytrain.append(data_train[i, 0])

xtrain, ytrain = np.array(xtrain), np.array(ytrain)
xtrain = np.reshape(xtrain, (xtrain.shape[0], xtrain.shape[1], 1))
print(xtrain.shape, ytrain.shape)

data_test = sc_data[data_train_len - 60 : , :]
xtest = []
ytest = close_price[data_train_len :, :]
for i in range(60, len(data_test)):
    xtest.append(data_test[i - 60 : i, 0])

xtest = np.array(xtest)
xtest = np.reshape(xtest, (xtest.shape[0], xtest.shape[1], 1))
print(xtest.shape, ytest.shape)

# Number of stock in training data
n_stocks = xtrain.shape[1]

#Model architecture parameters
n_neurons_1 = 1024
n_neurons_2 = 512
n_neurons_3 = 256
n_neurons_4 = 128

# Session
sesh = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Define two variables as placeholders
a = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, n_stocks])
b = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [1, None])

# Initializers
sig = 1
weight_init = tf.variance_scaling_initializer(mode = "fan_avg", distribution = "uniform", scale = 
sig)
bias_init = tf.zeros_initializer()

# Hidden weights
w_hid_1 = tf.Variable(weight_init([n_stocks, n_neurons_1]))
bias_hid_1 = tf.Variable(bias_init([n_neurons_1]))

w_hid_2 = tf.Variable(weight_init([n_neurons_1, n_neurons_2]))
bias_hid_2 = tf.Variable(bias_init([n_neurons_2]))

w_hid_3 = tf.Variable(weight_init([n_neurons_2, n_neurons_3]))
bias_hid_3 = tf.Variable(bias_init([n_neurons_3]))

w_hid_4 = tf.Variable(weight_init([n_neurons_3, n_neurons_4]))
bias_hid_4 = tf.Variable(bias_init([n_neurons_4]))

# Output weights
w_out = tf.Variable(weight_init([n_neurons_4, 1]))
bias_out = tf.Variable(bias_init([1]))

# Hidden layers
hid_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(a, w_hid_1), bias_hid_1))
hid_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hid_1, w_hid_2), bias_hid_2))
hid_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hid_2, w_hid_3), bias_hid_3))
hid_4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hid_3, w_hid_4), bias_hid_4))

# Transposed Output layer
out = tf.transpose(tf.add(tf.matmul(hid_4, w_out), bias_out))

# Cost function
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(out, b))
rmse = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(out, b)))

opt1 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(mse)
opt2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(rmse)

sesh.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Setup plot
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax1.plot(ytest)
line2, = ax1.plot(ytest * 0.5)
plt.show()

# Fitting neural network
batch_size = 256
mse_train = []
rmse_train = []
mse_test = []
rmse_test = []

# Run tensorflow
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):

  # Training data is shuffled
  shuffle_ind = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(ytrain)))
  xtrain = xtrain[shuffle_ind]
  ytrain = ytrain[shuffle_ind]

  # Minibatch training
  for i in range(0, len(ytrain) // batch_size):
    start = i * batch_size
    batch_x = xtrain[start : start + batch_size]
    batch_y = ytrain[start : start + batch_size]
    # Run optimizer with batch
    sesh.run(opt1, feed_dict = {a : batch_x, b : batch_y})
    sesh.run(opt2, feed_dict = {a : batch_x, b : batch_y})
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (256, 60, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_30:0', which has shape '(?, 60)'

This error appears for both of the last two lines under 'Run Optimizer with Batch'. How do I fix this?

Comment: what did you do to try figure this out yourself?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you trying to feed data that doesn't fit with place holder (I think you placeholder a), simple way to change your place holder to `a = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, n_stocks, 1])` or change your xtest and xtrain dimension (the line that you use reshape) by reduce last dimension using  `np.squeeze()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, I tried this and did not work.

Comment: Actually, what I mean is you were trying to put a numpy array with dimension (256, 60, 1) as a feed_dict to a placeholder of dimension (Any, 60). This problem can be solved by reshape your input to (256,60) so it fit with your placeholder or change your placeholder shape. you can check your dimension before using sess.run.